# Groovy JsonBuilder strange behavior when toString()

Tags: json, groovy, groovy-console, jsonbuilder

I need to create a json to use as body in an `http.request`. I'm able to build dynamically up the json, but I noticed a strange behavior when calling `builder.toString()` twice. The resulting json was totally different. I'm likely to think this is something related to a kind of buffer or so. I've been reading the documentation but I can't find a good answer. Here is a code to test.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def builder = new JsonBuilder()

def map = [
    catA: ["catA-element1", "catA-element2"],
    catB:[],
    catC:["catC-element1"]
]

def a = map.inject([:]) { res, k, v ->
    def b = v.inject([:]) {resp, i ->
        resp[i] = k
        resp
    }
    res += b
}
println a

def root = builder.query {
    bool {
        must a.collect{ k, v ->
            builder.match {
                "$v" k
            }
        }
    }
    should([
        builder.simple_query_string {
            query "text"
        }
    ])
}
println builder.toString()
println builder.toString()
```

This will print the following lines. Pay attention to the last two lines

```
[catA-element1:catA, catA-element2:catA, catC-element1:catC]
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"catA":"catA-element1"}},{"match":{"catA":"catA-element2"}},{"match":{"catC":"catC-element1"}}]},"should":[{"simple_query_string":{"query":"text"}}]}}
{"match":{"catC":"catC-element1"}}
```

In my code I can easily send the first `toString()` result to a variable and use it when needed. But, why does it change when invoking more than one time?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the _why_ of your question, but I think you meant to do `root.toString()`, not `builder.toString()`.

Comment: Very interesting. If you add `println builder.content` you'll see that internal structure was modified under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is happening because you are using `builder` inside the closure `bool`. If we make `print builder.content` before printing the result (`buider.toString()` is calling `JsonOutput.toJson(builder.content)`) we get:

```
[query:[bool:ConsoleScript54$_run_closure3$_closure6@294b5a70, should:[[simple_query_string:[query:text]]]]]
```

Adding `println builder.content` to the `bool` closure we can see that the `builder.content` is modified when the closure is evaluated:

```
def root = builder.query {
    bool {
        must a.collect{ k, v ->
            builder.match {
                "$v" k
                println builder.content
            }
        }
    }
    should([
        builder.simple_query_string {
            query "text"
        }
    ])
}

println JsonOutput.toJson(builder.content)
println builder.content
```

The above yields:

```
[query:[bool:ConsoleScript55$_run_closure3$_closure6@39b6156d, should:[[simple_query_string:[query:text]]]]]
[match:[catA:catA-element1]]
[match:[catA:catA-element2]]
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"catA":"catA-element1"}},{"match":{"catA":"catA-element2"}},{"match":{"catC":"catC-element1"}}]},"should":[{"simple_query_string":{"query":"text"}}]}}
[match:[catC:catC-element1]]
```

You can easily avoid that with a different builder for the closure inside:

```
def builder2 = new JsonBuilder()

def root = builder.query {
    bool {
        must a.collect{ k, v ->
            builder2.match {
                "$v" k
            }
        }
    }
    should([
        builder.simple_query_string {
            query "text"
        }
    ])
}
```

Or even better:

```
def root = builder.query {
    bool {
        must a.collect({ k, v -> ["$v": k] }).collect({[match: it]})
    }
    should([
        simple_query_string {
            query "text"
        }
    ])
}
```

Comment: I thought the same. Since all the time I was aware I was using the same builder object inside the bool closure. Having a different `JsonBuilder` instance helps to avoid the problem. And it must be true as well for the should closure. Thanks for the answer.